# What is the Response.Redirect equivalent in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I need to go another page or url. What is the response.redirect in silverlight?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want navigate to another page of Silverlight Navigation Application:

```
NavigationContext.Navigate( new Uri( "/Views/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative ) );
```

where NavigationContext - [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property

If you want navigate to another url:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"), "_blank");
```

Comment: There's no such method - NavigationContext.Navigate

Comment: @marko: it's not static method. Please, look at Page link which I provided: NavigationContext - is the property of Page class. Also, you can get NavigationContext from Frame instance. Remind, that for Silverlight Navigation Application.