# Is there a silverlight response.redirect equivalent?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to navigate from the codebehind of a Silverlight page back to an ASPX page in the same application.  How do I perform a "Response.Redirect" as I would from the codebehind of an ASPX page?  I've tried google and nothing comes up that actually works.  My silverlight form is of type UserControl.  I cannot change it to Page or sdk:Page nor embed an sdk:Page into the UserControl tag.  The Page always is unknown to the designer.

Comment: Is your application using the Navigation Framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I think the Navigation framework requires that the XAML be called as the page itself, not as a user control on an existing HTML page.  I need to host the user control on a normal ASPX page as we have a TON of navigation and menus in our page templates and the silverlight needs to simply be an element of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Response.Redirect equivalent in Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378037/what-is-the-response-redirect-equivalent-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

put this method somewhere:

```
    private string GetAbsoluteUrl(string strRelativePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strRelativePath))
            return strRelativePath;

        string strFullUrl;
        if (strRelativePath.StartsWith("http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          || strRelativePath.StartsWith("https:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
          || strRelativePath.StartsWith("file:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            strFullUrl = strRelativePath;
        }
        else
        {
            strFullUrl = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri;
            if (strFullUrl.IndexOf("ClientBin") > 0)
                strFullUrl = strFullUrl.Substring(0, strFullUrl.IndexOf("ClientBin")) + strRelativePath;
            else
                strFullUrl = strFullUrl.Substring(0, strFullUrl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) + strRelativePath;
        }

        return strFullUrl;
    }
```

Navigate via:

```
        string browserFeatures = "directories=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes,resizable=yes";
        HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(GetAbsoluteUrl("SomePage.aspx"), UriKind.Absolute), "_self", browserFeatures);
```

**Edit** - duplicate question here:

[What is the Response.Redirect equivalent in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378037/what-is-the-response-redirect-equivalent-in-silverlight)

with similar answer..